# Fazer uma conexão no banco MySQL criptografada

Tags: php, pdo, criptografia, conexão, senhas

Para fazer uma conexão ao banco MySQL uso esse código em PHP:

```
$host = "host";
$usuario = "usuario";
$banco = "banco";
$senha = "senha";
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$banco, $usuario, $senha);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Existe alguma forma de criptografar a senha e login? Pois o cliente achou inseguro esse arquivo com os dados de acesso assim solto no FTP....

Comment: Certo, você quer encriptar o login/senha... Para encriptar precisar de uma chave, onde então ficaria esta chave? Você pode utilizar variável de ambiente, isso remove as senhas do código, evitando que as senhas sejam salvas em multilplos lugares e também que sejam salvas usando `git` (e afins). Uma outra alternativa, mas radical, é criar um usuário usando o `REQUIRE X509` no usuário. Dessa forma, [você não usa "login/senha", mas utiliza certificados (que de qualquer forma terá que estar definindo em algum canto)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html#X509).

Answer (score 0):

O mais comum é usar variáveis de ambiente para armazenar credenciais de conexão com banco de dados.

É muito utilizado o padrão de arquivo `.env` (dotenv ou "ponto env") para gravar variáveis de ambiente. E para ler essas variáveis para o código você pode usar uma biblioteca como a [josegonzalez/php-dotenv](https://github.com/josegonzalez/php-dotenv).

**Para que isso seja seguro é importante que o arquivo `.env` fique fora da pasta acessível pela internet** (geralmente a public_html ou www).

Outra alternativa é configurar as variáveis de ambiente diretamente no servidor, mas requer algum conhecimento em administração de servidor. E então ler os valores usando a função [`getenv`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getenv.php).